# Why does one of my USB drive always start auto scan for virus when I plug in, others don't?

Tags: usb, anti-virus, autorun

I really don't want my USB drive to start auto scan for virus (which I can't even abort) every time I plug it into computer. My two other drives don't do that but this one drive always starts auto scan which is annoying.

I plugged it into a computer which seems to have self-installed some security staff but how I can remove that? I don't see anything unknown that I can remove.

It takes more than 15 minutes every time to complete this can which can't be aborted!

Answer (score 1):

It is a function of the Shell Hardware Detection service running inside Windows. The scan/auto-fix occurs when your computer recognizes the USB device was either unmounted improperly or there are errors in the file system.

To prevent it from happening you can disable that service, I found this article from howtogeek : https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35622/disable-scan-and-fix-for-removable-drives-in-windows/ - Where they go into step by step detailed instructions on how you can disable that service from startup, or terminate it temporarily.

Comment: Sorry I think my post allowed room for confusion, it mean auto scan for virus not fix disk. I have updated it.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. Which Anti-Virus software do you currently use?

Comment: It's Kaspersky End Pont security 10 for windows. Again I get this with one one flash drive, not the others. There is never any virus.